# Angular2 - 'router-outlet' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I created routes with deep child paths. I added `<router-outlet>` to the *AdminComponent* component which I wrapped into NgModule. But after refreshing the page I got this error:

```
'router-outlet' is not a known element
```

Maybe it occurred because I forgot import some module to *admin.module.ts*

Please help. Thanks.

*app.routes.ts*

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: LoginComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'admin',
                component: AdminComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'user',
                component: UserComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'there',
                component: ThereComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

*app.module.ts*

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutes,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (http: Http) => {
                return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './src/assets/i18n', '.json')
            },
            deps: [Http]
        }),
        UserComponentModule,
        AdminComponentModule,
        LoginComponentModule,
        ThereComponentModule,
        DashboardComponentModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        FormBuilder
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

*admin.component.ts* and *admin.module.ts*

```js
//  admin.component.ts
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'admin',
    template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>",
})

export class AdminComponent {
    constructor() {

    }
}

//  admin.module.ts
const ADMIN_DECLARATION = [
    AdminComponent
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        TranslateModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ADMIN_DECLARATION
    ],
    exports: [
        ADMIN_DECLARATION
    ],
    providers: [
        TranslateService,
        FormBuilder
    ]
})

export class AdminComponentModule {

}
```

Comment: I was just missing a `;`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`AdminComponent` is part of `AdminComponentModule` and you have not imported `RouterModule` inside  `AdminComponentModule` module:

```typescript
//  admin.component.ts
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'admin',
    template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>",
})

export class AdminComponent {
    constructor() {

    }
}

//  admin.module.ts
const ADMIN_DECLARATION = [
    AdminComponent
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        TranslateModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ADMIN_DECLARATION
    ],
    exports: [
        ADMIN_DECLARATION
    ],
    providers: [
        TranslateService,
        FormBuilder
    ]
})

export class AdminComponentModule {

}
```

Comment: Hi @yankee I am using lazy module feature and I have separated app.routing.module.ts file. if I include 'import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; and import in app.module.ts then again I face https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670232/routermodule-forroot-called-twice issue.  Request you to help if possible
'

Answer (score 46):

you did not export the RouterModule.

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this code

```typescript
import { provideRoutes} from '@angular/router';
```

to your `app.module.ts`

Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In your app.module.ts file

```typescript
import { routing } from './app-routing.module';

//and then write within imports
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    **routing**,
    EmployeeModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

Add schema `[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` in AppModule.

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  schemas : [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]  
})
```

Answer (score -1):

app.module.ts

```
import { MyRoutingModule } from './MyRoutingModulePath';

  @NgModule({
  imports: [
    MyRoutingModule
  ])
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: There is nothing original in my late answer. I struggled implementing solutions found over the internet. Exosting, confusing and time expensive because of my architectural particularities. I was looking for a short answer to point me to the solution instead of teaching me the process. After I finally managed it, it became obvious for me what it was difficult to observe in full examples. Sure, there are many ways to fail. But many will fail the same way as me. This answer is for those that are so close to fix it but far from getting it right.